# Determining which Window has the focus

Tags: gnome, window, focus

I'm trying to find a way so that I can tell at a glance which Window has the focus using Ubuntu 23.04. I'd like to do this via the titlebar being highlighted for the active Window and I have followed the accepted solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943147/different-colors-for-active-inactive-unity-window-title-bars?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However not all Windows titlebars are obeying the css. The Virtualbox, Chromium (browser), Calibre and Wine titlebars are all remaining unchanged and I do not understand why. I have tried logging out and rebooting after making the changes. I suspect it might have something to do with Gnome versions?